# How to calculate the strength ("space force") of dark matter within galaxies?

Tags: gravity, cosmology, black-holes, dark-matter, galaxies

Let's first have a look at the observed speed within galaxies ([source](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/33/Galaxy_rotation_under_the_influence_of_dark_matter.ogv)):
[image: measure of speed within galaxy]

On the left side we can see the speed of celestial bodies within galaxies derived by gravity only (gravity is usually created by a black hole at the center of a galaxy), on the right side we can see the observed speed of celestial bodies, both in respect of the distance from the galactic center.

As a result, the strength of dark matter (or "space force") could be calculated as:

$F$<sub>dark matter</sub> = $m$<sub>galaxy</sub> $\cdot$ $v$<sub>celestial body within galaxy</sub> $\frac{d}{dt}$ - $g$<sub>black hole, center of galaxy</sub>

Is this a viable calculation? And if so, are there any a graphs online which show this strength of dark matter (or "space force") in respect of the distance from the galactic center?

(Note: In this formula, a galaxy would be assigned a mass $m$<sub>galaxy</sub> much higher than the mass of its black hole. However, mathematically speaking one could also just decrease $dt$, so with a celestial body wandering from the center to the outskirts of the galaxy, $dt$ would decrease, hence the speed of time would increase. I doubt this is true because it would change the basic definition of speed $v$<sub>celestial body within galaxy</sub> as well and introduce all kinds of illogical contradictions, but in math everything is possible as we know from theory of relativity...)

**Addendum:**

- $m$<sub>galaxy</sub> $\cdot$ $v$<sub>celestial body within galaxy</sub> $\frac{d}{dt}$ $[kg·\frac{m}{s^2}]$ = observable force (shown in picture on the right)
- $g$<sub>black hole, center of galaxy</sub> $[kg·\frac{m}{s^2}]$, the force caused by gravity of a black hole (shown in picture on the left)
- $F$<sub>dark matter</sub> $[kg·\frac{m}{s^2}]$, the force of dark matter up until a point in space

Comment: Please explain your notation. What do $F_{\text{dark_matter}}$, $dt$ and $G_{\text{black hole}}$ mean ? Without knowing what your terms mean, it is not even clear that your formula is dimensionally correct.

Comment: $mvd/dt$ is the force that is supposed to be caused by dark matter up until a point within the galaxy (shown in the right picture). $G_{black−hole}$ is the force that is caused by the black hole's gravity (shown in the left picture). $F_{dark-matter}$ is the difference...

Comment: Hope that addendum will clarify things...

Comment: "Note that the gravity usually comes from a black hole at the center of a galaxy)". No it doesn't.

Comment: @Rob: Changed some notations, I think it's pretty clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation seems to be trying to express the gravitational contribution of dark matter as the difference between the observed gravitational force on a star at a given distance from the centre of a galaxy and the theoretical gravitational force based on the stars that can be seen in the galaxy.

This is pretty much what the velocity/distance curves show. The difference between observed and theoretical gravitational force can be worked out from the rotational velocity at a given distance because the centripetal force required to keep a star in a galactic orbit with speed $v$ and radius $r$ is proportional to $\frac {v^2}{r}$.

The super-massive black hole which lies, we believe, at the centre of most galaxies makes only a very small contribution to the gravitational attraction of the galaxy as whole. The typical mass of such a black hole is around $1 \%$ of mass of the stars in the galaxy, or around $0.1 \%$ of the total galactic mass including dark matter.

Comment: Because of its complexity, I split this question in parts, here's the first part handling "only" $g_{black-hole}$: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/584522/how-to-calculate-the-gravitational-force-of-a-black-hole-outside-event-horizon-a